# SQL Join - get rows that meet criteria from foreign key table

Tags: sql, join

I need to find the rows in one table that meet specific attributes specified in a foreign key table.

I have these two tables:

```
ITEM
PK: ItemId
Text: nvarchar

ITEMATTRIBUTE
PK: ItemAttributeId
FK: ItemId
AttributeText: nvarchar
Value: int
```

ItemAttribute has a foreign key to Items and defines dynamic attributes given for an item.
e.g:

```
ITEM:
ItemId  Text
1       ItemA
2       ItemB
3       ItemC

ITEMATTRIBUTE:
ItemAttributeID ItemId  AttributeText       Value
1               1       AttributeA          10
2               1       AttributeB          10
3               2       AttributeA          8
```

I need to dynamically find items which have certain itamAttributes.
For example the desired query shall return items that have

> AttributeA AND AttributeB: result should show only **ItemA**.

When I (left) join both tables I get a row for each item with the joined itemattribute:

```
select * from item i left join itemattribute a on i.itemid=a.itemid
```

However I need a dynamic way to get items where defined itemattributes are set:
get all items that have AttributeA with a value > 5 and AttributeB with value > 5: result ItemA

As I don't know how many itemAttributes are set I can't do the query with stacked subselects or hardcoded as in:

```
select distinct i2.itemid from item i2, itemattribute a2, 
(select i.itemid, a.attributetext from item i left join itemattribute a on i.itemid=a.itemid where AttributeText='AttributeA' and value > 5) ii
where i2.itemid=a2.itemid and a2.attributetexT='AttributeB' and value > 5
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. `I need to dynamically find items which have certain attributes.` Dynamically? Are you trying to write something like a stored procedure?

Comment: No, I want a hint to achieve the result as described(!) in the post with a select, maybe pivoting?

Comment: So are you saying that you want to choose an attribute qualifier, say >5 and get all items that have all attributes >5?

Comment: Yes, but with multiple itemAttributes at the same time. As stated above I want a select showing all items that have attributeA and also have attributeB. Which would result in ItemA. But of course there could also exist Attribute C and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate your values to the Item level, then do the logic to filter for the Items you want.

In some dbs (like Snowflake) you can run a `PIVOT`, but in most you need to do conditional aggregations.

```
SELECT item_id, att_a_value, att_b_value
FROM (
SELECT
   i.item_id
   ,max(CASE WHEN ia.AttributeText = 'Attribute A' THEN ia.value END) as att_a_value
   ,max(CASE WHEN ia.AttributeText = 'Attribute B' THEN ia.value END) as att_b_value
FROM Items i
LEFT JOIN ItemAttributes ia ON i.item_id = ia.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id
) z
WHERE z.att_a_value > 5 AND z.att_b_value > 5
```